# java reset counter and close program with JOption pane

Tags: java

When my JButton is clicked 5 times I want to show a dialog asking if the user wants more questions

Yes or No

Yes should reset counter to 0 and allow more questions to be asked,

No should close out program when Clicked in the dialog box.

The way I have it now is resetting counter to 0 and I am not sure where to add the

```
 System.exit(0);
```

here is my code

```
 b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                 clicked++;

                 if (clicked >= 5) {
                     Object[] options = {
                                        "No, thanks",
                                        "Yes, please"
                                        };
             JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
             "Would you like more math questions? ",
             "Math Questions",
             JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,   System.exit(0);
             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
             null,
             options ,  
             options[1]);
                 } else {
                     clicked = 0;
                 } 
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
  {

    clicked++;

    if (clicked >= 5) {

      Object[] options = {
        "No, thanks",
        "Yes, please"
      };

      int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
        "Would you like more math questions? ",
        "Math Questions",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        options ,  
        options[1]);

      if (response == 1) 
        clicked = 0; //reset
      else
        System.exit(0);
    } 

  }
});
```

Comment: Would you mind adding that to my code in your example im not understanding what your code is doing in reference to mine.

Comment: I updated it.  You called System.exit() on line 14 also, that needs to go.

Comment: OK thank you, it works perfectly. One question for you, I was wondering at first the dialog pops up before showing the next answer. but if you keep going it shows up before showing a question. How can I make it show up before showing the next question every 5 question insteads of clicks? could I change click to the actual function++ or something like that?

Comment: Hrm.  I need to see how your calling the method in your code, want to just throw it up on http://pastebin.com/ and I'll take a look.  Just the class file where your calling the dialog.

Comment: I saw what you changed. But this just changes it to 10 everytime. first time it stops on a questions next an answer... How can I get it to for sure always ask the dialog box while showing an answer.